# Issue with Javascript IN operator

Tags: javascript

I have a little issue regarding `IN` operator in javascript.

As we know that [simplifies redundant logical ORs](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/using-javascripts-operator).

I have the following statement:

```
if(value==="abc" || value==="cde" || value==="efg" || ...){
 ...
}
```

I could use

```
if(value in { "abc":1, "cde":1, "efg":1, ... }){
  ...
}
```

I wrote this as an example but Google Chrome Console get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: It works for me. Could you provide a full demo of `in` which throws the syntax error?

Comment: In what browser did you use that? It works for me ..

Comment: @davids: No sorry :) We're here to learn.

Comment: In chrome, using Visual Studio 2010. I cleared the cache but ...

Comment: IMO using `['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].indexOf(value)` is more readable.

Comment: It works fine Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/mday5/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome: `var value = "abc";
var foo = { "abc":1, "cde":1, "efg":1};
if(value in { "abc":1, "cde":1, "efg":1}){
        console.log('1');
}
/* Output: 1 */`

Comment: @Lèsemajesté — Except that you need to compare it such: `> -1`

Comment: Solved...I made some mistakes in other side of code... Thanks all for replies.

Comment: @Quentin: what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid bugs in case somewhere in your app `Object.prototype` has been modified, you should use:

```
if(({ "abc":1, "cde":1, "efg":1, ... }).hasOwnProperty(value)){
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a safer approach, but it doesn't explain why the code in the question isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use like this.

```
var foo = "bar";

if ( foo in { bar:1, foobar:1, foo:1 } ) {
  alert("yes")
} else {
  alert("No")
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is working fine. What changes are you suggesting? Why?

Comment: well i have not tested code that is in question, i thought may be some mistakes in that code, and i know how it should be so i suggested my code.

Answer (score -1):

Your coding should be...

```
if(value in { abc:1, cde:1, efg:1}){
        //...
        }
```